# GDAL - TypeError Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'CoordinateTransformation_TransformPoint'

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff, osgeo

I am trying to run some GDAL operations inside my Anaconda environment. However once I upgraded my gdal and other packages the program crashed.

Environment: Anaconda

```
Package               Version                  Channel
GDAL                   3.3.0                   pipwin
fiona                  1.8.20                  pipwin
geopandas              0.9.0                   pipwin
shapely                1.7.1                   pipwin
pyproj                 2.6.1.post1             py37hcfa1391_1
```

Here is the offending code.

```
    crsGeo = osgeo.osr.SpatialReference()
    crsGeo.ImportFromEPSG(int(proj_type))
    t = osgeo.osr.CoordinateTransformation(crs, crsGeo)
    (lat, long, z) = t.TransformPoint(posX, posY)<-------------------
    srs = osgeo.osr.SpatialReference(wkt=prj)
```

And the raster's metadata.

```
proj:  GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
    SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],
    AXIS["Longitude",EAST],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
proj type:  4326
```

The code threw the following error.

```
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: C:\Users\Deployment\.conda\envs\sw_py37_cv45    \Library\share\proj\proj.db lacks DATABASE.LAYOUT.VERSION.MAJOR / DATABASE.LAYOUT.VERSION.MINOR metadata. It comes from another PROJ installation.
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: C:\Users\Deployment\.conda\envs\sw_py37_cv45\Library\share\proj\proj.db lacks DATABASE.LAYOUT.VERSION.MAJOR / DATABASE.LAYOUT.VERSION.MINOR metadata. It comes from another PROJ installation.
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create: unrecognized format / unknown name
ERROR 6: Cannot find coordinate operations from `GEOGCRS["WGS 84",DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],CS[ellipsoidal,2],AXIS["latitude",north,ORDER[1],ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],AXIS["longitude",east,ORDER[2],ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],ID["EPSG",4326]]' to `'
Could not calculate crsGeo spatial reference.
F:\Sliding_Windows\GeoTiff.py, line 402: TypeError Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'CoordinateTransformation_TransformPoint'.
Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
OSRCoordinateTransformationShadow::TransformPoint(double [3])
OSRCoordinateTransformationShadow::TransformPoint(double [4])
OSRCoordinateTransformationShadow::TransformPoint(double [3],double,double,double)
OSRCoordinateTransformationShadow::TransformPoint(double [4],double,double,double,double)
```

Based on previous posts, it seems that proj.dll is missing from some PATH variable. My environment only has a proj_6_2.dll, and even with that added to my system's PATH, the error persists.

I have tried to put posX and posY inside tuples/list as well, but that did not help.

Is this a package mismatch issue? Missing dependencies issue? Or was there a change in how TransformPoint should be called?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the image or vector file you are using. It should be mismatched or not projected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).